# What's [app]? Application?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What purpose does tag [app](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app) serve?

It has almost 40 questions. Few of them I looked at made me feel like it's the same as [applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) tag. Does it make sense to make them synonyms?

Comment: “App” is often used in the more limited sense of *mobile* applications. It is arguably a better-defined term than “application”. It would make very much sense to keep them separate.

Comment: @amon we've got [tag:mobile-app] tag, how about synonymizing to it (non-mobile questions in [tag:app] would have to be retagged then)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...

An [app](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app) is definitely an [applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications). It may present questions spanning many platforms like [web-applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications), [desktop-applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-applications), [mobile-app](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-app), and so on. And on the grounds of my first sentence, yes: the *app* and the *applications* tags should be synonyms.

However, if one considers semantics, this may not be the right course of action. [applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) may refer to the the *applying* of different principles like things from [design-patterns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns), [architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture), or [algorithms](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms). In this case, making them synonyms may be counterproductive.

If Programmers.SE could survey the questions under [applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) and see what categories the majority fall into, a better informed decision can be taken